# How to connect wireless printer to dd-wrt AP with WPS?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, printer, dd-wrt

I recently [updated the firmware](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WNDR4500) of my router ([Netgear WNDR4500](http://www.netgear.de/support/product/WNDR4500.aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic)) to dd-wrt. I am not sure about the version I have, but everything is working flawlessly, and since I did it the day before yesterday (21.03.17), I don't only think the firmware is the correct one, but also that it is the most recent one. I enabled the `WPS/SES` button [as described in dd-wrt guide](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SES_Button), since I need my printer (I have a Samsung M2070W printer, whose manual is to be found [here](http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_DE&CttFileID=6412736&CDCttType=EM&ModelType=N&ModelName=SL-M2070W&VPath=EM/201602/20160223183207594/M207x_QIG1_worldwide_for_customer.pdf)) to be connected to the network, but I think it doesn't work.

In fact, I press and hold the `WPS` button on the printer until it begins to search for a wireless network, then press the `WPS` button on the router, and nothing happens (I tried to press and hold that one too).

Given that it's not possible to manually enter the security key (if it can be of any help I have WPA2 Personal with AES), I would have no other option than connect the printer to the router via USB cable, which kinda bothers me. Any idea on how to get the WPS work (is the WPS the problem anyway?)?

P.s. 1: Both wireless interfaces (2.4 and 5 GHz) are tested and working, and yes, I did the 30/30/30 reset after the installation of the firmware.

P.s. 2: I read that `WPS` button didn't work on dd-wrt, but all the sources are pretty much outdated, and I thought the bug was corrected...

Comment: Not the same question - but it provides a workarround which will solve your issue  - http://askubuntu.com/questions/557965/trying-to-connect-a-samsung-m2020w-printer-to-wireless-network - and btw, you should not use wds as its very insecure.

Comment: I know that, but thanks for pointing it out :) I would have enabled it for the printer, and then disabled it again. Are you sure this is possible? It looks like there is a ethernet cable port, but it's sealed by plastic (the USB, on the contrary, is not).

Comment: Dont know for sure. Knowing what I now know I would not buy a Samsung printer (I have a different model - dont like vendor lockin on consumables). Are you sure the sealed pladtic isnt just a removable gromit? (ive seen this on other printers - presumably to stop noobs plugging the fax line into it.)

Comment: Look at this: http://www.samsung.com/my/business/flagship/SL-M2070W-XSS/images/configuration03.png

Comment: Looks like you are SOL. Can you return the printer (or borrow an AP/router you can use to set the printer up using WDS?)

Comment: No I bought the printer more than 2 years ago. I could borrow another router and do what you say, if it comes to that... but I'd rather understand if WPS is possible anyway

Comment: I cant help with that (I do hope dd-wrt doesnt allow it - wds needs to die). Reading online, you might be able to remove wifi authentication altogether to allow the printer to connect, then reconfigure it.

Comment: I currently have the same issue with a Brother printer. It would appear that WPS is not enabled in dd-wrt for security reasons. However, like the link to the askubuntu workaround in @davidgo 's comment, there are other methods to get wifi working. With the Brother I can establish a direct connection via USB and use Brother's utilities to set the wifi.

Answer (score 2):

dd-wrt does not support WPS, due to inherent security issues. The button can be repurposed for other functions - like turning the radio on and off. To set up a printer for wifi when the printer doesn't have an onboard interface, you will need to establish a direct connection to the printer. Then use the manufacturer's software tools to set up wifi on the printer. Apparently one can also establish a connection using a mobile printing app to do the same function - connect to the printer and setup wifi that way.

[DD-WRT: WPS not supported](https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=1077332&sid=6492afbabcc9b8f844f3da05cf414e91)

[Brother support: setup wifi through direct connection](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl2270dw_all&faqid=faq00002794_004)

[askubuntu: setup printer wifi through mobile app](http://askubuntu.com/questions/557965/trying-to-connect-a-samsung-m2020w-printer-to-wireless-network)